# Where-Object filter unexpectedly matches the whole input collection, Get-Member shows collection type instead of element type

Tags: powershell, filtering, enumeration

My `Get-AzureStorSimpleAccessControlRecord` call returns 2 objects, with
`Name` property values `servertest4` and `servertest3`.

However,

```
Get-AzureStorSimpleAccessControlRecord | where {$_.Name -like '*servertest4*'}
```

is unexpectedly returning *both* objects.

If I pass it through a for-each loop, the where statement is working to capture that property.

```
Get-AzureStorSimpleAccessControlRecord | % {$_.Name} | where {$_ -like 'servertest4'}
servertest4
```

Passing the original command to `Get-Member` unexpectedly doesn't show the `Name` property. Is that the problem?

If so, why does it have it as a column and why does it work when I pass it through the for-each loop? This is all it returned for properties (I stripped the methods out):

```
Get-AzureStorSimpleAccessControlRecord | gm


   TypeName: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.StorSimple.Models.AccessControlRecord, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.StorSimple, 
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]

Name           MemberType            Definition                          
Item           ParameterizedProperty 

Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.StorSimple.Models.AccessControlRecord Item(int index) {get;set;}                                   
Capacity       Property              int Capacity {get;set;}                                                                                                              
Count          Property              int Count {get;}                                                                                                                     
IsFixedSize    Property              bool IsFixedSize {get;}                                                                                                              
IsReadOnly     Property              bool IsReadOnly {get;}                                                                                                               
IsSynchronized Property              bool IsSynchronized {get;}                                                                                                           
SyncRoot       Property              System.Object SyncRoot {get;}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `gm -input (Get-AzureStorSimpleAccessControlRecord)[0]`

Comment: `Name                Property   string Name {get;set;}` does show up. what's the difference between running gm that way and piping the output into it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that **`Get-AzureStorSimpleAccessControlRecord` is ill-behaved** and **sends its output collection *as a whole* through the pipeline**, as a *single object*, instead of *element by element*.

You should be able **work around that by enclosing the call in `(...)`**:

```bash
(Get-AzureStorSimpleAccessControlRecord) |
  Where-Object { $_.Name -like '*servertest4*' }
```

Enclosing the call in `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--) makes PowerShell *enumerate* the collection, i.e. it sends its *elements one by one* through the pipeline, as is normally expected.

---

##### Optional reading: What happens *without* the workaround?

The following simplified example simulates `Get-AzureStorSimpleAccessControlRecord`'s undesired behavior by creating an `[int[]]` array that is *artificially wrapped* in another array by way of the unary form of the array-construction operator, `,`.
Sending this *wrapped* collection through the pipeline causes it to be sent *as a whole* instead of item by item.

```bash
$wrappedColl = , [int[]] (1, 2) # create artificially wrapped collection
```

Now, `Get-Member` reports the wrapped *collection type* instead of the type of the individual items, as normally happens (the pipeline unwrapped the *outer* array and sent its only element - the inner `[int[]]` array - as-is):

```bash
PS> $wrappedColl | Get-Member

   TypeName: System.Int32[]  # !! Type of the wrapped array as a whole
   ...
```

The array being passed as a whole also gets in the way when applying a `Where-Object` filter, which is what prompted the question:

```bash
# Trying to extract element 2 outputs the whole array(!).
PS> $wrappedColl | Where-Object { $_ -eq 2 }
1
2
```

- Since the `[int[]]` array is passed as a whole, that's what `$_` is bound to inside the `Where-Object` script block.
- Applying `-eq` to a LHS that is an *array* performs *array filtering* rather than returning a simple `[bool]` value, so that  `[int[]] (1, 2) -eq 2` returns the *array* of matching items, which in this case is `[object[]] 2` (note the result array is alway a regular PS array, of type `[object[]]`).
- The resulting (single-item) array is then interpreted as a *Boolean* in the context of the `Where-Object` cmdlet, and any non-empty array evaluates to `$true` when coerced to a Boolean.
- Therefore, since the script block passed to `Where-Object` evaluated to `$true`, the input object is *passed through*, which in this case is, as stated, the *whole* `[int[]]` array.

Comment: Aha! I was having the same issue with Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2PipelineRun, which also returns all data at once, and your solution worked perfectly. Thanks for being so thorough in your explanation.